# Move comments in the WordPress site

Tags: wordpress, comments, move

Hello friends

How do I display a comment in a html box?

in one page I want to move the comments!

link

Comment: ask your question in details.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this very issue a while ago. I resolved it using the following plugin:

https://nl.wordpress.org/plugins/copy-or-move-comments/

Hope this helps!